# make undo apply to drop-down menus and check boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, undo

I am using Chrome. I have a page with multiple controls. I make changes in an text input, then to a drop-down (select) control, then to a check box or radio button, and then to second text input. I then press control-z once, and it undoes the change in the second text input. I press control-z again and it undoes the change in the first text input. Is there a way in to make this built-in multiple-undo process include changes to drop-down (select) controls and check boxes / radio buttons, without having to write custom code to save values, track edits, capture control-z events, etc.? I know that code is not terribly hard, but if there's a way to make it just happen that would be nice.

I only care about Chrome, so it's okay if there's a Chrome-specific way to do this.

Comment: do you have a fiddle containing the code with the working `ctrl + z` dropdown / checkbox?

Comment: @RamondeVries, I can put one together, but they are just a normal `<select>` control and normal `<input type="checkbox">` with no events attached. For the text input undo behavior, you can see for instance the Stack Overflow profile edit page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/<your_number>. You can modify your Display Name and then your Location, and then you can press control-z twice.

Comment: i feel like this is not going to work, since `ctrl+z` is a standart control wich only edit's the selected input and then goes back to those you've edited before if the input is empty. so in order to succeed you will need to program a code that detects the `ctrl+z` action and when that's actived, find the objects that are changed and put it back to original state.

Comment: Right, I know that it only undoes text control edits by default, but I was wondering why it doesn't also undo <select> change check box changes, and whether it could.